# Why does this sed line do this?

Tags: sed

Why does this produce these results?

```
C:\>(echo a  &&  echo b) | sed "1!G;h;$p"
a
b
a
b
a

C:\>
```

Added-
I see now there is no question, that it'd give those results.. but

(added note- 2nd line = last line. But I see you wrote last line to emphasise that it's $ matching the 2nd line as last line.  I accept that notation.  Also, 1st line, 2nd line, last line, refer to lines of input.)

Jonathan, you wrote
a - 1st line, pattern space
b - 2nd line, pattern space, line 1
a - 2nd line, pattern space, line 2
b - last line, $p pattern space, line 1
a - last line, $p pattern space, line 2

But wouldn't it be
Note- Dennis's comment has confirmed that the "But wouldn't it be" is correct

a - 1st line, pattern space
b - last line, $p pattern space, line 1
a - last line, $p pattern space, line 2
b - 2nd line, pattern space, line 1
a - 2nd line, pattern space, line 2

i.e. the same output
a
b
a
b
a

But the descriptions of how it did the b  a, is the other way around

That's assuming the $ operates on the last line, and not after it..

But what you wrote makes it look like the $ operates after it.

Comment: Your question is complicated by the use of double quotes `"` because some shells (bash, zsh, csh) will interpolate `!` inside there and all shells will do something with `$p`.  Most shells immediately fail if you paste that in with "!G event not found" but ones that didn't (like ash) interpolated "$p" to "" and didn't have the right output.

Comment: @Ben Jackson     The cmd.exe shell likes it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `1!G` appends the hold space to the pattern space after the first line.
- `h` copies the pattern space to the hold space (on every line).
- `$p` prints the last line (again).

The first input line is 'a'; the G command is ignored; the line is copied to the hold space; the line is printed (because you didn't say `-n`).

The second input line is 'b'; the G command appends the hold space ('a') to the pattern space ('b'); the 'h' command copies the pattern space to the hold space; the pattern space is printed once because of the 'no `-n`'.

There is no more input, so the `$p` acts and prints the pattern space.

So, you get:

- `a` - 1st line, pattern space
- `b` - 2nd line, pattern space, line 1
- `a` - 2nd line, pattern space, line 2
- `b` - last line, $p pattern space, line 1
- `a` - last line, $p pattern space, line 2

---

The question is asked: did I tag the pairs of 'b/a' lines backwards?

Good question: not sure...how would we find out?

Let's add another operation to the '$' set:

```
(echo a; echo b) | sed -e '1!G;h;$p;$s/b\na/X'
```

The output is:

```
a
b
a
X
```

which shows that the `$p` print does occur before the `$s///` operation, which occurs before the final print of the pattern space.

One side-effect of this observation, which caught me by surprise (but makes sense on reflection), is that `sed` knows when it is processing the last line as it is running the script on the last line.  That means it does read-ahead after the newline to see whether there is more data to fetch.  [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) shows that the [sed source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/execute.c) at about line 928 contains a function `test_eof()` which does indeed do one character of lookahead.

*(One of the good things about SO is that you learn even as you teach!)*

<s>So, somewhat to my surprise, it seems that `sed` knows when it has reached the last line before it processes it - so it seems to do some sort of read-ahead.  Either that or I've misunderstood something really badly, or it's too late and I need to go to sleep.</s>

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler   Hang on.. I now understand why the output is ababa And I see your solution explains an output of ababa. But where you wrote "So, you get". It looks like you are saying the $p runs last.  I thought the printing of the pattern space is done after the commands are run, isn't it? What you write, suggests that $p is something that runs not on the last line, but on the EOF marker? Is that right?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler So the last line SED reads, would be a kind of EOF line and it runs its commands on that too. is that right?

Comment: Yes, the `$` is the address of the last line, *not* an EOF.

Comment: @Dennis: I'm not disputing that $ is the address of the last line.  I'm just not sure how `sed` determines that the current line is the last line unless it reads ahead to see if there is any data left to read.  I suppose looking at the source should reveal all...I'm not sure whether I have to do that.  And your comment to @barlop is only saying more succinctly what my amendment says (but then your comment doesn't actually explain the observation).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Impressive that you wrote some code to demonstrate what was correct.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I hadn't noticed your edit for some reason..(but yes now I do!) So Dennis's comments, I think both were meant for me, were very useful as comments to me.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I guess maybe it'd still need a read ahead type thing even if sed were to have been different and used EOF? since there isn't actually an EOF character in the file.

Comment: Sed could of course do it via a byte count..if not even with a test at each line, but just reading in x bytes, the size of the file. that seems simplest. but if it was a read ahead method, it does far more sort of reading ahead to grab a line. from that perspective it's just reading ahead one more character than it would otherwise.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, I just wanted to confirm it since your last sentence seemed to express some doubt. According to the source, if I'm reading it right, it checks to see if the input is empty, tries `feof()` and tries to `getc()` after the current line (followed by an `ungetc()`). So, yes, read-ahead. [Around line 928](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/execute.c).

Comment: @Dennis, @barlop: sorry for the confusion.  The observation that 'sed' knows that it is the last line before it processes it was pretty much incontrovertible given the test.  What was confusing me - was somewhat unexpected - is that it does a readahead to find out.  My original comments were based on a somewhat simpler (too simplistic) model of operation for sed.  But, given that the '$' rules could appear anywhere in the script, the 'go back and process the last line again' stuff wouldn't work.  Thanks for the source URL, Dennis.  I'll fix up the tail my message.

Comment: I think  Sed doesn't go forward or backwards, and process any other line 'cos it just processes one line at a time. I think sed processes every single line and while doing so, when any address matches, be it 3 or $, that command is executed. So even if it is  sed -n "/c/,/q/p" on a file, then it processes every line from beginning to end. I know java but not c. But I guess it could work by tripping a boolean. So, $ like 2 or 9 or any other address, wouldn't be a request to process another line.

Comment: @barlop: you're right that sed doesn't go backwards.  However, sed has to know when it has reached EOF on the last file (or standard input - and remember that the input could be a pipe, which has no size) so that it can process the '$-qualified' commands in the sed script.  And, as demonstrated in the code that Dennis pointed us to, there is a function `test_eof()` that does readahead to find out whether it has reached EOF on the last file.

Comment: i'd note that in your answer, line 2 and last line are synonymous.  But funnily enough, that output piped to sed, does include a third line 'cos the data echod is a\nb\n  and the third line has nothing on it. But it seems Sed ignores a blank line at the last line of the file. so if you give sed a file g.j of 3 blank lines. so file whose hex is 0d 0a 0d 0a or 0a 0a. You can do "1s/.*/z/" you can do "2s/.*/z/" g.j  but "3s/.*/z/" won't replace/match anything. i guess that's right, perhaps you or @DennisWilliamson has a thought on the correctness of my comment here. ta

Comment: @barlop: If your file contains 4 characters, hex 0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A, then it contains 2 lines each ended with CRLF (carriage return, line feed). It does not contain 3 lines by any definition I know of. If the file contained those 4 characters followed by one other, say 0x61 (`a`), then opinion is divided. The C standard says that is no longer a text file because it does not end with a newline. Most Unix program treat the `a` as a 'line'; some will add a newline, others will leave the newline out. With the two-line input, it does not surprise me that `sed '3s/.*/z/'` won't replace anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Looking at the C standard - ANSI C / ISO 9899. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf    it says regarding \n "Moves the active position to the initial position of the next line"   I can't see anywhere it saying that a line must end with a \n(eg/ie for a text file). And that quote makes it sound like when it ends in a \n it means there is another line coming. doesn't it? And where does it say about a line must end in a \n?

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011, Section §7.21.2 **Streams** says: _A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line
consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the
last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined._  ISO/IEC 9899:1999 said substantially the same in the equivalent section. So, the last line may or may not need a newline, depending on the implementation. However, the newline terminates a line — it is not a line separator. Some programs don't handle a missing last newline well.

Answer (score 0):

first line of input is 'a'
second line of input is 'b'

Sed reads the first line of input(a) into the pattern space and runs through the commands. Of the commands, of which there are three. 1!G is skipped as that only applies(appending the pattern space to the holding space) when it's not the first line. h copies the pattern space to the holding space. $p doesn't apply. Then after running through the commands it prints the pattern space.  It prints 'a'.  Note the holding space is still 'a' and will be even just after the next line is read into the pattern space. The pattern space is currently 'a' but will change -being overwritten- when the next line is read in.

Sed reads the second line of input(b) into the pattern space, note the holding space is still 'a'. It then runs 1!G appending the holding space(a) to the pattern space(b), giving a pattern space of 'b\na' and a holding space of 'a'.  The next command is 'h', which copies the pattern space (b\na) into the holding space, giving a holding space of 'b\na' though we see the holding space here isn't that relevant. The next command is $p which applies since the second line of input (which is the line of input we are on) is also the last line of input, and so as mentioned, $p applies and  prints the pattern space so we get b\na printed.   Then the pattern space gets printed again, because as with the first line, after all commands are run, the pattern space is printed.  So reading the second line of input (which is the last line of input), we get b\na and again b\na.   The first occurrence of b\na is from the $p, the second occurrence is from the printing of the pattern space that occurs after all commands are run.

```
a  <------- Reading first line of input. Printing the pattern space that happens after the end of the commands.
b\na     <---- Reading second line of input(which is the last line of input), hitting the $p command. That command didn't apply in the case of the first line of input.
b\na  <--- Still on the second line of input(which is the last line of input), printing the pattern space that happens after the end of the  commands.
```

(note, one might ask.. should it be a\n,   and  b\na\n. i.e. shouldn't there be a new line character at the end of the pattern space since they are lines.. and *nix uses \n as line terminator rather than line separator. Maybe.. But I think in the case of the sed pattern space it maybe doesn't have a \n at the end. I read in the sed manual that the append commands work such that, if they are to append 'text' to the pattern space or holding space, they append a \n followed by that 'text'. So that would suggest the pattern space doesn't end with a \n but i'm no expert)